# Подгрузка контента через ajax в вордпресс

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Нужно подгрузить контент из другого файла в div с классом .content

```
$('.pages_list a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var postId = parseInt( $(this).attr('data-catid') );
    postviewCountGet(postId);
});

function postviewCountGet(postId){  
   $.ajax({
    success: function(html){
        $( ".text" ).load( "/posts.php" );
        }
    });         
};
```

В корне сайта есть файл posts.php

```
<?php
  echo "result";
?>
```

Вот его содержимое нужно вывести в блок с классом .content. Выдает ошибку

> jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 GET http://hitechbuld/posts.php 404 (Not Found)

На самом деле файл posts.php есть в корне сайта. 
Как этот вопрос решить в WordPress ?

Comment: Вот всё, что в success, только без всяких аяксов.

Comment: То есть так достаточно ?

Comment: function postviewCountGet(postId){ 
 $( ".text" ).load( "/posts.php" );
};

Comment: Выдает ошибку   GET http://hitechbuld/posts.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Ошибка в пути к файлу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".text" ).load( "<? echo bloginfo('template_url') . '/posts.php'?>" );
```

Вот так сработало

Comment: + что не поленились дорешать задачу.

Answer (score 0):

```
function postviewCountGet(postId){
    $(".content").load("/path/to/file");
};
```

В .content залетит всё из post.php.